# Comparing heterogenous lists of lists

Tags: python, list

Comparing two lists is tough, there are numerous posts on this subject. But what if I have a list of lists? Simplified to extreme:

```
 members=[['john',1964,'NY'], \
          ['anna',1991,'CA'], \
          ['bert',2001,'AL'], \
          ['eddy',1990,'OH']]

 cash   =[['john',200], \
          ['dirk',200], \
          ['anna',300], \
          ['eddy',150]]
```

What I need are differences and intersections:

```
 a     =[['john',1964,'NY'], \
         ['anna',1991,'CA'], \
         ['eddy',1990,'OH']]    #BOTH in members and cash

 b     =[['bert',2001,'AL']]    #in members only
```

Usually I handle this with a loop, but I feel it is time to switch to a more pythonic way.

The big problem is that I have to fish out the whole (sub)list while comparing just it's first element. The only way I imagine is to make two sets of names, compare these and recreate the lists (of lists) from the sets of differences. Not much better than a loop.

Comment: If you are looking for differences and intersections, use sets. I don't know why you think that that is not much better than a loop: it's a lot more elegant, and mathematically the correct approach.

Comment: What are you comparing on in the first place? Not on the state or number, I guess? Just the names?

Comment: Loops ARE Pythonic. Are you saying you have a working solution and are looking for an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Usually I handle this with a loop, but I feel it is time to switch to
>   a more pythonic way.

Nah, I disagree. This *is* pythonic, depending on who you ask. Here's what you'd need to do -

1. Generate sets
2. Find the intersection and difference
3. Use the keys from step 2 to build `a` and `b`

```
members_set = {m[0] for m in members}
cash_set = {c[0] for c in cash}

inter = members_set & cash_set
diff = members_set - cash_set 

a = [m for m in members if m[0] in inter]
b = [m for m in members if m[0] in diff]
```

```
print(a)
[['john', 1964, 'NY'], ['anna', 1991, 'CA'], ['eddy', 1990, 'OH']]

print(b)
[['bert', 2001, 'AL']]
```

Comment: GREAT! I still have a lot of learn.
P.S. I am not dogmatic whether a loop is pythonic, so let's say your solution is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `pandas` solution, which avoids having to *explicitly* define loops yourself. I only recommend this solution if you are looking to perform further manipulations.

```
import pandas as pd

members = [['john',1964,'NY'],
           ['anna',1991,'CA'],
           ['bert',2001,'AL'],
           ['eddy',1990,'OH']]

cash = [['john',200],
        ['dirk',200],
        ['anna',300],
        ['eddy',150]]

df_members = pd.DataFrame(members, columns=['name', 'year', 'state'])
df_cash = pd.DataFrame(cash, columns=['name', 'value'])

mask = df_members['name'].isin(set(df_cash['name']))

members_common = df_members[mask].values.tolist()
members_membersonly = df_members[~mask].values.tolist()

# members_common
# [['john', 1964, 'NY'], ['anna', 1991, 'CA'], ['eddy', 1990, 'OH']]

# members_membersonly
# [['bert', 2001, 'AL']]
```